# JSP/HTML page loading / rendering is taking too much time in Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, loading

JSP/HTML page loading / rendering is taking too much time in Internet Explorer (IE).

Same JSP/HTML page is loaded/rendered in Firefox very fastly.

IE is taking 4 mins to load a JSP/HTML page and same page is loaded in Firefox in 1 mins 20 seconds.

It's really surprise to me.

What is the reason for taking too much time in Internet Explorer (IE) for page loading / rendering ?

How to design a web page, which will load/render faster in IE ?

Comment: Do you have lots of Javascript ?

Comment: Yes. total size for all java scripts is 400 KB

Answer (score 1):

MSIE is known to have a slow table renderer. But a loading time of over 1 minute is insane. Are you displaying a HTML table with a zilliion of records? Consider pagination. Strive to a max page loading time of 5 seconds, preferably less than 3 seconds. Your current problem is not MSIE.

---

**Update** as per the comments: Don't use client side pagination. Use server side pagination. If necessary with help of Ajax. It will solve your problem of unnecessarily hauling the entire table data into browser's memory and causing slow load and render time and bad user experience.

And once again, MSIE has just an extremely poor performing table renderer and JS engine. Firefox is simply the better browser. There's no why, that's a fact.

Comment: Yes, we are displaying HTML table for showing records. Have also implemented JS client side pagination for same.

Comment: Total no. of DOM elements on page is 46870  .

Comment: My worry is How FireFox is showing this in very short time considering IE time.

Comment: We are displaying huge data in a HTML table. 600 table is created while rendering the page, inside of parent HTML table. Each inner HTML table are used to display huge data. Each inner HTML table has 600 line of DOM elements.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Now rewrite the code/logic to do the job more efficiently. Paginate on the server side and don't unnecessarily store data in the HTML which the user ain't going to see.

Comment: That means we have to remove HTML table from my page design. i think, now i have to use DIV for page layout instead of HTML table. Am i right ?

Comment: Depends on the functional and technical design which are unclear as far now.

Comment: Now end user got addicted to use the page that is not get refreshed while use of pagination or any other actions.

Comment: @Santosh - if the end-user has got used to the whole 600 records in the page, try and wean him off IE onto Firefox :)

Comment: Yes, IE is a poorly developed webbrowser. That's a known fact. throw IE away and grab Firefox, Chrome or Safari. They're simply better. Unfortunately half of the world isn't aware of that yet.